# How to catch EntityStreamSizeException thrown by withSizeLimit Directive

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have created a post request in akka http to upload a file

Here is my code

```
final val MEDIA_FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE = 30 * 1024 * 1024

def uploadMediaObjectForASite(): Route = path("Some path") {
  userId =>
    post {
      parameter(Symbol("location_id").as[String]) {
        locationId =>
          withSizeLimit(MEDIA_FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE) {
            withRequestTimeout(120.seconds) {
              entity(as[Multipart.FormData]) {
                formData =>
                  val metadataList = List(TITLE, DESCRIPTION, UPLOADED_BY)
                  // extract file parts and start the upload process
              }
            }
          }
      }
    }
}
```

If I use a file greater than 30MB I get a 400 BadRequest in postman with following message

> EntityStreamSizeException: incoming entity size (47350868) exceeded size limit (31457280 bytes)! This may have been a parser limit (set via `akka.http.[server|client].parsing.max-content-length`), a decoder limit (set via `akka.http.routing.decode-max-size`), or a custom limit set with `withSizeLimit`.

I have tried following approach
a) using handleException directive

```
 val customExceptionHandler: ExceptionHandler = ExceptionHandler {
    case _: EntityStreamSizeException =>
      complete(StatusCodes.PayloadTooLarge, "File size exceeded the limit of 30MB")
  }

def uploadMediaObjectForASite(): Route = path("Some path") {
  userId =>
    post {
        handleException(customExceptionHandler) {
            parameter(Symbol("location_id").as[String]) {
            locationId =>
              withSizeLimit(MEDIA_FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE) {
                withRequestTimeout(120.seconds) {
                  entity(as[Multipart.FormData]) {
                    formData =>
                      val metadataList = List(TITLE, DESCRIPTION, UPLOADED_BY)
                      // extract file parts and start the upload process
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

b) using handleRejection directive

```
val customRejectionHandler: RejectionHandler = RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
    .handle {
      case EntityStreamSizeException(limit, actualSize) =>
        complete(StatusCodes.PayloadTooLarge, s"File size exceeded the limit of ${limit} bytes")
    }
    .result()

def uploadMediaObjectForASite(): Route = path("Some path") {
  userId =>
    post {
        handleRejection(customRejectionHandler) {
            parameter(Symbol("location_id").as[String]) {
            locationId =>
              withSizeLimit(MEDIA_FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE) {
                withRequestTimeout(120.seconds) {
                  entity(as[Multipart.FormData]) {
                    formData =>
                      val metadataList = List(TITLE, DESCRIPTION, UPLOADED_BY)
                      // extract file parts and start the upload process
                  }
                }
              }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

But none of them works

How can I catch this exception and provide custom message.

Comment: you may configure limits with standard [akka http settings](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/configuration.html). Look at two `max-content-length` options and also for `request-timeout`

Comment: I got it working, there was a issue in my code. while performing extraction of file parts I was catching the exception and handling that there only. So my customExceptionHandler did not get the chance to handle the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the directives `handleExceptions()`/`handleRejections()` like this:

```
  val handleErrors = handleExceptions(customExceptionHandler) &  handleRejections(customRejectionHandler)

  val routes: Route = {
    handleErrors {
      concat(uploadMediaObjectForASite, myOtherRoute)
    }
  }
```

Also see this [working example](https://github.com/pbernet/akka_streams_tutorial/blob/7256a4d35ffef977857591e210ba2b9c68ddcf5e/src/main/scala/akkahttp/SampleRoutes.scala#L32). Not sure why your approach is not working though, although I just see the `handleExceptions`directive in 10.5.2 (and not `handleException`). Also I see that the response `PayloadTooLarge` is deprecated in favour of `ContentTooLarge`.